# How to use a bind variable in trigger body?

Tags: plsql, oracle11g, database-trigger

I'm new to PL/SQL. I'm using oracle 11g XE along with sql developer. I'm trying to create to create  an after insert trigger as follows

```
create or replace trigger tr1
after 
insert ON
employee
for each row
begin
 print :new.emp_id;
end;
```

The employee table is as follows

```
create table employee
( emp_id varchar2(5) primary key,
  emp_name varchar2(10),
  salary number,
  company varchar2(10) foreign key references companies(comp_name)
);
```

When I run the statement I got a 'enter binds' window for the bind variable :new. But I was confused that why do  I need to enter the value for :new since it is pseudorecord. Then I entered 'employee' as the values for :new. Now I'm getting the following error.

```
Error(2,8): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "" when expecting one of the following:     := . ( @ % ; The symbol ":=" was substituted for "" to continue.
```

Comment: When you compile it, SQL developer will ask you to enter the bind variable. Just leave them blank. They are not the source of the error here. When the trigger runs on Insert, the value of :new.emp_id will be the one inserted into the table. It will be populated automatically. Compile the trigger, then try to insert to test.

Comment: @Hawk. Thank u for the reply. I have compiled it. But its having the error which I specified in the question.

Comment: If the problem is SQL Developer popping up prompts then please tag your question `sqldeveloper`. I'm not familiar with it myself.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not in the `:new` pseudorecord. The error is coming from the usage of [print](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQPUG/ch_twelve031.htm#SQPUG051), which is used to print the bind variable used in *successful* PL/SQL block or used in an EXECUTE command.  For example, you can use it this way:

```
VARIABLE n NUMBER   
BEGIN  
:n := 1;  
END;  
/
```

Then

```
PRINT n;
```

But if you want to test the value being inserted, you can use DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE like this:

```
create or replace trigger tr1   
after    
insert ON   
employee   
for each row   
BEGIN   
 dbms_output.put_line(:new.emp_id);   
END;   
/
```

Enable DBMS_OUTPUT window in your SQL Developer, then run

```
insert into employee values(1, 'empName', 1000, 'ABC');
```

You'll see `1` printed out.

However, you can always test the value from the table. Because the value should be already inserted into table. You can just query.